# Conditional expectation with mean-preserving spread

Tags: probability, conditional-expectation, conditional-probability, convolution, cumulative-distribution-functions

I have a question which I believe relates to stochastic dominance. I have a random variables $Z \in \lbrace 0, 1 \rbrace$ and $X \in \mathbb{R}$, where $X \sim F_X$ is continuous. I use these to construct a random variable $A = f(Z,X)$, where $f$ is some continuous function such that $f(1,x) \geq f(0,x)$ for all $x$.

I have another random variable $B = A + E$, where $E \sim F_E$ is some mean zero noise. I want to know if the following is true in general and, if not, under what conditions it is true.

$E[F_A(A) \mid Z = 1] - E[F_A(A) \mid Z = 0] \geq E[F_B(B) \mid Z = 1] - E[F_B(B) \mid Z = 0]$

So far I've observed that $B$ is a mean-preserving spread of $A$ and so $A$ should second-order stochastically dominate $B$. Can I use stochastic dominance to tackle this problem? Thanks very much for your thoughts.

Comment: I am not sure I understand the inequality.  Are you missing a few $E[.]$ operators, or perhaps missing some parentheses?

Comment: I suppose a related claim is whether $E[F_A(A) \mid Z = 1] \geq E[F_B(B) \mid Z = 1]$ and $E[F_A(A) \mid Z = 0] \leq E[F_B(B) \mid Z = 0]$.
Basically, I want to know whether the expected position of $A$ on its CDF $F_A$ is greater (smaller) than the expected position of $B$ on its CDF $F_B$ when $Z = 1$ ($Z = 0$). Intuitively I feel this should be true since the mean zero noise effectively reduces the correlation between $Z$ and $A$ but I am not sure how to prove it.

Comment: OK so on the LHS you mean something like $E[F_A(A) \mid Z=1] - \color{red}{E}[F_A(A) \mid Z=0]$, correct?  missing the red $\color{red}{E}$?  same for RHS.  i just wanna understand the exact math stmt (inequality) you're conjecturing.  :)

Comment: Oh wow, I double checked but completely missed the missing $E$. Yes, thanks for pointing that out, you are right.

Comment: (1) Is $E$ meant to be not just zero-mean, but also independent of everything else?  (That would be the normal assumption, but I just wanna confirm.)  (2) Are $Z, X$ meant to he independent?  (I'm not sure what you had in mind)

Comment: (1) $E$ is independent of everything else, yes. (2) I haven't assumed $Z$ and $X$ are independent. However, if this assumption is needed for the result to hold, it wouldn't be unreasonable for the application I have in mind.

Answer (score 1):

Not a (full) answer / too long for a comment.

If $Z, X$ can be dependent, then the conjecture can be false, because between $X$ and $f$ it is easy to make $Z=1 \implies$ a lower $A$.  Here is a specific counter-example:

- $Z \in \{0, 1\}$ with equal prob $\frac12$
- $X = -2Z$
- $A = f(Z, X) = Z + X = -Z \in \{-1, 0\}$ with equal prob $\frac12$
- $F_A(a) = P(A \le a) = 0, \frac12, 1$ in the regions $(-\infty, -1), [-1, 0), [0, +\infty)$ respectively.

$$LHS = F_A(-1) - F_A(0) = \frac12 - 1 = -\frac12$$

- $E \in \{-10, +10\}$ with equal prob $\frac12$
- $B = A + E \in \{-11, -10, 9, 10\}$ with equal prob $\frac14$, and $F_B$ has $4$ equal sized steps at those points.

$$RHS = {F_B(-11) + F_B(9) \over 2} - {F_B(-10) + F_B(10) \over 2} = \frac12 (\frac14 + \frac34 - \frac12 - 1) = -\frac14$$

$$Gap = RHS - LHS = \frac12 > 0$$

Note that for simplicity I used discrete variables above, but you can easily add a tiny bit of "fuzz" around $X$ and/or $E$ e.g. $X = -2Z + Uniform(0,0.0001)$ and it would perturb the numbers a bit, but the gap should only be slightly perturbed from $\frac12$ and still be $> 0$.

---

Further thoughts: My gut feel is the conjecture is true if $Z,X$ are independent, but I haven't been able to prove that.

Comment: Thanks very much. This is very useful even if not a full answer.